# Using Pundit to resolve association scope

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, pundit

Example code:

```
#model
class Profile < AR:Base
  has_many :projects
end

#controller
class ProfilesController < AC
  def show
    @user = Profile.find(params[:id])
  end
end

#view

@profile.projects.each do |project|
  = render something
end
```

Any user can view any profile, but projects should be filtered by visibility (like public/private projects).

I'm concerning to add one more ivar because it violates Sandi Metz's rule

> Controllers can instantiate only one object. Therefore, views can only
>   know about one instance variable and views should only send messages
>   to that object (@object.collaborator.value is not allowed).

The only way I see it now is to introduce another class (facade) to do this things, like:

```
class ProfilePresenter
  def initialize(profile, current_user)
    @profile = profile
    @current_user
  end

  def visible_profiles
    ProjectPolicy::Scope.new(current_user, profile.projects).resolve
  end
end
```

Am I missing something?

How would one achieve it (resolving association scopes) using Pundit?

In case we will need pagination for projects within profile view - what approach to choose?